# Get cart contents from my custom module in Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

In my magento, I have added a product to cart - so I see the following on the checkout page:

[image]

I have a custom module with a `TestController` with a `IndexAction` where I want to retrieve the current contents of basket for custom processing. This will be used to provide a "get delivery cost estimate" type functionality.

I.e. customer will add bunch of items into basket (as guest), click a button on front end and it takes them to our module where they will enter the destination country and postcode and we will do some custom processing to let the customer know what the estimated delivery cost is going to be.

I tried to retrieve the basket contents like this:

```
$cart_contents = Mage::helper('checkout')->getQuote();
foreach ($cart_contents->getItemsCollection() as $item) {
   var_dump($item->getName());
}
exit;
```

This does not return anything.

I also tried a different approach:

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$cartItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
echo "<pre>";
foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
    print_r($item->getData());
}
exit;
```

This is also returning nothing.

Bear in mind; this is a guest checkout (i.e. customer is not logged in).

To test there is a valid quote; I did the following:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r(Mage::helper('checkout')->getQuote()->getData());
echo "<hr>";
print_r(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getData());
exit;
```

This is what I get back:

```
Array
(
    [store_id] => 5
    [is_checkout_cart] => 1
    [remote_ip] => 90.xxx.xxx.xxx
    [x_forwarded_for] => 90.xxx.xxx.xxx
)
Array
(
    [store_id] => 5
    [is_checkout_cart] => 1
    [remote_ip] => 90.xxx.xxx.xxx
    [x_forwarded_for] => 90.xxx.xxx.xxx
)
```

Answer (score 0):

## You can use following script to get cart items on your custom controller action.

```
$itemsCollection = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();
$itemsVisible = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
$items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();
<?php foreach($items as $item) { ?>     
    <p class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $item->getProductUrl();?>"><?php echo $item->getName(); ?></a></p>
    <span class="price"><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($item->getPrice(),true,false);?></span>
    <span class="qty">Qty: <?php echo $item->getQty(); ?> </span>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I have just tried this also, it's returning empty. This is so strange.

Comment: which magento version are you using?

Comment: `Magento ver. 1.9.1.0`

Comment: it should work, there might be some other problem in your case because i just tested it on the same version. Is your cart page showing all items?

Comment: can you try this code to place on any phtml file, just for testing purpose, need to confirm if your module has some issue.

Comment: The module is a very very basic module. It just has one controller and one action. Tested it on phtml view and no luck either.

Answer (score 0):

This is Magento code for getting the cart item; try it:

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();

if($cart->getAllItems()):
    foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item):
        echo $item->getProduct()->getName();
    endforeach;
endif;
```

Comment: It's empty again. I can see the items in the cart though.

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked. Thanks!

Comment: @Hatchet this is magento code for getting the cart item. there is no need of explanation.